# No module named 'pagedown'

Tags: python, django, markdown

I am doing the following steps:

1. activated virtual environment
2. `pip install django-pagedown`
3. Added `pagedown` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
4. `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` and tried `python manage.py collectstatic`

added this in `forms.py`

```
from pagedown.widgets import PagedownWidget

class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget())
```

Getting this error in VSCode that couldn't import `PagedownWidegt`, and getting above stated error in terminal.
how do I solve it? Thank you

Comment: I might be worth mentioning if this error occurs only in django context. Does "import pagedown" work if isolated from the rest of your code?

Comment: I just imported pagedown it is not working either

Comment: Shouldn't the app be added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, and not in forms.py?

Comment: yes, I added the app in INSTALLED_APPS and in forms.py I added its widget above code

Comment: I just tried to reproduce it. `pip install django-pagedown` > `import pagedown` works. Python 3.6.1. Is it possible that you are working with multiple python versions and installed it to the wrong one?

Comment: i just run `python --version` and it returned Python 3.7.2

Comment: (new-blog.03) PS E:\Practice\backups\new-blog.03\src> py -0p
Installed Pythons found by C:\WINDOWS\py.exe Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64        "C:\Users\Basir Payenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" *
 -3.7-64        "C:\Users\Basir Payenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" *
 -3.7-32        "C:\Users\Basir Payenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"
 -3.7-32        "C:\Users\Basir Payenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"

Comment: `pip --version` will tell you both which version of pip you have as well as which Python is it associated with. Is it associated with the correct one?

Comment: pip 19.1.1 from e:\practice\new-blog\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

there it is